# strings.Trim is removing the letter "i" (golang)

Tags: go

```
full path: views/admin/users.html
trim set (views): /admin/users.html
trim set (views/): admin/users.html

full path: views/index.html
trim set (views): /index.html
trim set (views/): ndex.html
```

Heres my code:

```
    err := filepath.Walk("./views", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if strings.Contains(path, ".html") {
            bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            fmt.Println("full path:", path)
            fmt.Println("trim set (views):", strings.Trim(path, "views"))
            fmt.Println("trim set (views/):", strings.Trim(path, "views/"))
        }
    }
```

Have I lost my mind? Does the forward slash have something to do with this? Please explain what's going on if you know.

Comment: "Trim returns a slice of the string s with all leading and trailing Unicode code points contained in cutset removed."

Comment: Perhaps you want `TrimPrefix`

Comment: Thanks! Clearly I need to get some sleep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter to [strings.Trim()](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Trim) is a 'cutset', ie, a set of runes to remove from the strings, and 'i' is one of them.

To return all but the last element of path, use [path.Dir()](https://golang.org/pkg/path/#Dir).

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `strings.Replace`:

```
fmt.Println("full path:", path)
fmt.Println("trim set (views):", strings.Replace(path, "views", "", -1))
fmt.Println("trim set (views/):", strings.Replace(path, "views/", "", -1))
```

Result:

```
full path: views/index.html
trim set (views): /index.html
trim set (views/): index.html
```